# read_excel inserting \n into dataframe's column header?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Quick question - I have a bit of Python code that reads in a spreadsheet as a dataframe:

```
xl = "myspreadsheet.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(xl, sheet_name = "mysheet")
```

Something odd happens when this runs - the column header 'Cancelled(Y/N)' gets converted to 'Cancelled\n(Y/N)' in the dataframe. Does anyone know why the \n is being inserted please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your column label in Excel header row has a line feed to make the column label show `Cancelled` and `(Y/N)` in separate lines.

Comment: Yes, I think someone's used Alt+Enter to make them show on different lines. Is \n how Python registers this then?

Comment: @SRJCoding  Yes, Python uses `\n` for newline

Comment: @SRJCoding and newline  corresponds to the line feed introduced by Alt + Enter